# Updating Classes that inherit from abstract classes

Tags: python, class, inheritance, abstract, abc

I have an abstract class `ship`.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
class ship(ABC):
    def __init__(self):
         ...

    @abstractmethod
    def do_stuff(self,stuff,things):
         pass
```

I have multiple classes that inherit from it (`destroyer`,`cruiser`,`patrol_boat`, etc...)

```
class carrier(ship):
    def __init__(self):
         ....
    def do_stuff(self,stuff,things):
         ....
```

Currently, if I were to add, let's say `def do_more_stuff(self):` to `ship`

```
class ship(ABC):
    def __init__(self):
         ...

    @abstractmethod
    def do_stuff(self,stuff,things):
         pass

    @abstractmethod
    def do_more_stuff(self,stuff,things):
        pass
```

The changes would not affect any of the subclasses until I reentered them into the console.  How do I change this?

Comment: You need to give enough code to show what you actually did ([MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/MCVE)). Editing the super _class_ to add new methods should work (it's mildly inefficient to do so after the subclasses are defined, but not unreasonably so), but I suspect you're mistakenly editing _instances_, or not editing the class at all.

Comment: I feel like I'm redefining `ship` while leaving the remaining classes to inherit from the previous definition of `ship`.  How could I add functions to `ship` without reentering the entire block?

Comment: You're correct about redefining the whole class not changing what the subclasses inherit from. My answer covers the details here; there is a way that works for non-abstract methods, but abstract methods cannot use this technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you actually redefine a class from scratch, it's a different class; the subclasses are still inheriting from the old version of `ship`. You can't just define a new class named `ship` and expect the subclasses to find it magically.

Normally, if you wanted to monkey-patch `ship` after creation to add new methods, you could just do something like:

```
def do_more_stuff(self,stuff,things):
    pass
ship.do_more_stuff = do_more_stuff
```

But unfortunately, `abstractmethod`s for `ABC`s [are an explicit exception to this rule](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.abstractmethod):

> Dynamically adding abstract methods to a class, or attempting to modify the abstraction status of a method or class once it is created, are not supported.

You must either define the abstract base class completely up front, or redefine the entire class hierarchy later if you want to add new abstract methods to the base class.

Comment: Could I add regular methods to the base abstract class without encountering this problem?

Comment: @David: That should not cause problems. The magic is involved with the combination of the `ABCMeta` metaclass and the `abstractmethod` descriptor magic; the metaclass hooks are invoked at the moment you end the class definition block (thus the requirement to define all abstract methods with the class), and `ABCMeta` is specifically concerned with `abstractmethod`, not regular methods.  As long as you don't try to replace existing abstract methods or add new ones, it should work just fine; new concrete methods can't change the rules for abstract inheritance.